# Cannot transrcibe pseudocode into C ( MPI for HykSort algo )

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, mpi, pseudocode

I need to implement a sorting algorithm HykSort, but having trouble with reading the symbols of the pseudocode it provides.
For example something like |B| mean? [do,dk] <-- [0,n]
The upside A I guess is for each?

[image: This is the code]

Comment: Pseudocode doesn't follow actual fixed rules, so it's up to the author to pick a style that they like. BTW: What does this have to do with MPI or the C language?

Comment: This looks like a highly formalized type of pseudocode. Whatever textbook contains it should define it.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Well as I say in the title, I need to implement this algorithm written in pseudocode in C using MPI library but having a hard time understanding the explanation, with that signs it makes it even harder.

Comment: @JohnColeman It is in this paper [Hyksort A new variant...](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~hari/files/pubs/ics13.pdf), it does provide the meaning of set variables, but not the symbols

Comment: The paper gives a link to C++ source code which should fill in the details. My guess is that |B| is the length of B and [a,b] <- [c,d] is a way of denoting two assignments in 1 line.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, there is a code online, but again its implementation is not very well written, no comments at all, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Azrail I see what you mean. "No comments at all" is a bit of an exaggeration, but the key sections which do the heavy lifting are mostly uncommented. A more fundamental problem is that the provided code doesn't map to the pseudocode in any clear way (e.g. not the same function names and certain `mpi_` functions in the pseudocode don't seem to appear in the source at all. It is hard, for example, to see what variable corresponds to "color". Perhaps you could shoot someone an e-mail asking for clarification.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have already did, also some comments on youtube videos that have some related algorithm